# OfficeRuntime.storage.setItems fails to set items in storage, return Unknown Error

Tags: javascript, office-js, excel-addins

I am creating an add-in for Excel. The add-in has a custom function as well as a taskpane where the user can login and perform actions.

I am calling OfficeRuntime.storage.setItems in order to save the user's details (email, token, etc.) in the storage after the user is logged in. In Excel web it works properly (the items are saved in storage) but in Excel desktop this call fails, and the error returning from the promise is "Unknown: an unknown error has occurred".

The add-in is installed via the store. The Excel version is 2019.
This bug does not happen to all users, only some of them.

This is the code that fails:

```
OfficeRuntime.storage
      .setItems({
        [CONSTANTS.TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY]: token,
        [CONSTANTS.USER_ORGANIZATION]: getDomainFromEmail(username),
        [CONSTANTS.USER_EMAIL]: username,
        [CONSTANTS.FLOW_ID]: actualFlowId
      });
```

Anyone else experienced an issue with setItems?

Comment: Is it possible to share manifest file which is helpful for debugging?  Or you may can share the name of the add-in and I can try to install from the store.